# how to put an alert in the onFocus event of an input without loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, alert

I'm trying to add a confirm popup when entering into an input.

The problem is that when I close the alert, input have lost the focus and re-clicking in alert fires again

Even if I set focus by code when popup closes then popup fires again

Here a sample code

```js
$('#CodMadre, #CodFup').focus(function() {
  if ($("#DataInizio").val()) {
    bootbox.alert({
     title: "Attenzione",
     message: "second input has value, you will lose it",
    })      
  }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" ></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootbox.js/4.4.0/bootbox.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="CodFup" name="CodFup" placeholder="Focus this" class="form-control" value="" pattern="[0-9]*" data-error="Inserire il codice attività" />
<input type="text" id="DataInizio" name="SelAnno" class="form-control datepicker" data-error="obbligatorio" required value="dffd" />
```

My next problem is to make the same thing on a bootstrap select (by [silvio moreto](https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/)) where I don't have a focus() event available

Comment: Don't use `alert()` elements for this. There's no way to avoid the focus event loop with them, as focus returns to the previous element and triggers the alert again. Use HTML to display a message instead. This is better practice anyway, as showing alerts to users are both ugly and a little amateurish.

Comment: He is using bootbox alert. not window.alert

Comment: He would be if it was uncommented :)

Comment: onestly i started with a plain message in html near the input but found some problems in showing and hiding hem so i hoped to make it easier with a popup

Comment: i try to add bootbox in snippet but did't found a way to make it work here

Comment: Your bootbox will fix the problem, you just need to uncomment the JS which instantiates it, and include Bootstrap in your page

Comment: You could always use `.one()` for example: `$("#CodMadre, #CodFup").one("focus", function(event){` if you only want this event to execute once...

Comment: in my project i use bootbox but still have the same issue

Comment: when i close bootbox confirm the input has lost focus and reclicking the popups fires again

Comment: I fixed your snippet to be a [mcve]

Comment: @NewToJS i need the action to be exetuded again if users make other changes

Comment: thanks @mplungjan onestly i thought bootbox absence was not so relevant, sorry

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan tanks to mplungjan now you can see that bootbox don't prevent the loop: is not possible to edit the first input

Comment: It prevents it fine for me, but you now can't type in the box at all as it loses focus when the alert is shown. I'd strongly suggest showing some inline HTM for this which doesn't affect the focus in anyway

Comment: yeah, maybe it's the best way. i up vote your first comment